# IDataObjectAsyncCapability not being handled by Outlook in OLE Drag and Drop

Tags: node.js, winapi, drag-and-drop, electron, ole

I work on an electron application, and we would like to support dragging and dropping .msg files from our app into Outlook (or the Windows shell, or wherever, but primarily Outlook). The files will not necessarily be available before the user starts the drag and drop operation, and will need to be downloaded once the user begins the drag and drop. This means we can't use electron's inbuilt `startDrag` as it requires that the files are already in the filesystem, so I have implemented a node c++ addon to handle it using the OLE Drag and Drop API.

The data extraction (from my app to Outlook) needs to occur asynchronously, otherwise node's event loop will be blocked, halting the download. This means that the data extraction has to occur on another thread so that the event loop can continue actually downloading the data (currently doing the download in c++ is not an option, it has to occur in node). So I have implemented `IDataObjectAsyncCapability` on my DataObject, to indicate that I support asynchronous data extraction (it would be even nicer to be able to indicate that I *don't* support synchronous), but Outlook won't even *query* for the Interface, let alone do the data extraction asynchronously. The Windows shell does however query for the interface, but after the call to `GetData`, it still performs the extraction synchronously inside `DoDragDrop`, without even invoking any of the `IDataObjectAsyncCapability` methods. Is there something lacking in my implementation, or a specific way to encourage the drop target to start up a new thread?

Here is the meat of my DataObject implementation, if there's anything else that could be of use, I can provide.

```
STDMETHODIMP DataObject::QueryInterface(REFIID iid, LPVOID* ppvObject) {
    if (ppvObject == nullptr) {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    } else if (iid == IID_IUnknown) {
        AddRef();
        *ppvObject = reinterpret_cast<LPUNKNOWN>(this);
        return S_OK;
    } else if (iid == IID_IDataObject) {
        AddRef();
        *ppvObject = reinterpret_cast<LPDATAOBJECT>(this);
        return S_OK;
    } else if (iid == IID_IDataObjectAsyncCapability) {
        AddRef();
        *ppvObject = reinterpret_cast<IDataObjectAsyncCapability*>(this);
        return S_OK;
    }

    *ppvObject = nullptr;
    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}
```

```
STDMETHODIMP DataObject::GetData(LPFORMATETC queryFormat,
                                 LPSTGMEDIUM outputStorage) {
    if (queryFormat->cfFormat == CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR &&
        (queryFormat->tymed & TYMED_HGLOBAL) && queryFormat->lindex <= 0 &&
        queryFormat->dwAspect == DVASPECT_CONTENT) {
        outputStorage->tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        outputStorage->pUnkForRelease = nullptr;
        outputStorage->hGlobal =
            lockAndDuplicateHGLOBAL(this->groupDescriptorStorage.hGlobal);
        return S_OK;
    } else if (queryFormat->cfFormat == CF_FILECONTENTS &&
               (queryFormat->tymed & TYMED_ISTREAM) &&
               queryFormat->dwAspect == DVASPECT_CONTENT &&
               queryFormat->lindex >= 0 &&
               queryFormat->lindex < this->files.size()) {
        // files is vector<pair<FILEDESCRIPTOR, STGMEDIUM>>
        // where the STGMEDIUM is set to IStream
        // Am I doing something wrong here?
        auto file = this->files[queryFormat->lindex].second;
        *outputStorage = file;
        return S_OK;
    }
    return DV_E_FORMATETC;
}
```

```
STDMETHODIMP DataObject::QueryGetData(LPFORMATETC queryFormat) {
    if (queryFormat->cfFormat == CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR ||
        (queryFormat->cfFormat == CF_FILECONTENTS &&
         (queryFormat->tymed & TYMED_HGLOBAL))) {
        return S_OK;
    }

    return DATA_E_FORMATETC;
}
```

```
STDMETHODIMP DataObject::EnumFormatEtc(DWORD dwDirection,
                                       LPENUMFORMATETC* ppEnumFormatEtc) {
    if (dwDirection == DATADIR_GET) {
        // basic implementation of IEnumFormatEtc (not mine)
        return EnumFormat::Create(this->supportedFormats, this->numFormats,
                                  ppEnumFormatEtc);
    }
    return E_INVALIDARG;
}
```

```
// Do the actual drag drop
// files is a list of STGMEDIUMS with IStreams. I'm using data that's readily available while
// implementing this, could that be somehow interfering and causing this problem in the first place?
DWORD dwEffect;
auto dataObject = new DataObject(groupDescriptorStorage, files);
auto dropSource = new DropSource();

// Do these DROPEFFECTS have an effect?
auto result = DoDragDrop(dataObject, dropSource,
                             DROPEFFECT_COPY | DROPEFFECT_MOVE, &dwEffect);

// By the time we get here, the data extraction would already have occured 
// because it's happening inside DoDragDrop. of course, isAsyncOperation will be false
BOOL isInAsyncOperation;
dataObject->InOperation(&isInAsyncOperation);
```

I've followed the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/datascenarios) as well as various forum posts I've found, but I can't seem to find anything about what to do when the drop target doesn't play ball.
I'm really stuck for ideas as to how to make this work. If the drop target isn't even querying for `IDataObjectAsyncCapability` then is it hopeless? Should I be returning something other than the file contents when it's first requested?

Comment: IDataObjectAsyncCapability is optional (and therefore often useless since only few targets use it). Fact of life is Outlook doesn't uses it, it mostly supports only CFSTR_FILECONTENTS + CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR. If you implement your own IDataObject, you can serve CFSTR_FILECONTENTS as an on-demand stream, so you don't have to block anything.

Comment: That's what I thougt, but outlook isn't returning from its Drop call until its finished reading all of the data, meaning I stay stuck inside DoDragDrop until all the data is read. Do you know if its possible to signal that the data is coming but not ready yet so that outlook might return early then try extracting? I tried returning E_PENDING from the stream but outlook just gives up and shows an error message.

Comment: There's no way to do this differently. You can see this "blocking" behavior when drag&dropping a big file from the Shell (Explorer view) to Outlook. Using a stream is much better than using an HGLOBAL though.